# Is it possible to send the state to the page destination at the time of browser back with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react.js and react-router-dom to create two pages. Form.js is the page where you enter your name in the form, and Confirmation.js is the page where you confirm the name.
I want to share the state of two classes. So, when you jump to another page from the link button, you will send the state at the same time. The sent state is received in the class constructor as `this.state = props.history.location.state`.

[image]
Many have omitted this code.

```js
//Form.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const histState = props.history.location.state
    this.state = histState == undefined ? {name: this.state} : histState
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleFormInputChanged} value={this.state.name}/>
        <Link to={pathname: "/confirmation" , state: this.state}>Send</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
//Confirmation.js
class Confirmation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.history.location.state
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Your Name : <span className="name">{this.state.name}</span></div>
        <Link to={pathname: "/form" , state: this.state}>Edit</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now I can do what I want to do. However, I noticed that when the user pressed the browser back button on the Confirmation.js page, the state was not sent because it jumped to the Form.js page without pressing the Link component.

As a solution, I added the following code to Confirmation.js.

```js
//Confirmation.js
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.history.push("/form", this.state)
}
```

However, when I do a browser back this way and receive a state in the class constructor, `props.history.location.state` is undefined. And strangely, after a while or reloading, `props.history.location.state` is set to state normally.

```js
//Form.js
constructor(props) {
  ...
  console.log("Form constructor", props.history.location.state)
}
```

[image]

I want to resolve the time it takes for state to be set as the value of `props.history.location.state`, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass basic parameters as route segments, like `/form/:username`, or you could use a query parameter like `/form?username=Hiroaki`, but passing around data more structured or complex via the url or location history seems inadvisable.

I think you'd save yourself a lot of pain by using context or setting up a simple orthogonal store to keep track of it as the user navigates.

Here's a sketch of how you might do it with context. Assuming the provider is above the router in the component hierarchy, the form state will persist through navigation (though not through page reloads). (I haven't tested any of this code. This is just to give you a sense of it.)

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({});

<FormStateContext.Provider value={formState}>
  <Form onChange={setFormState} />
</FormStateContext.Provider>
```

```
const Form = ({ onChange }) => {
  const formState = useContext(FormStateContext);

  return (
    <input name="username"
      value={formState.username}
      onChange={(e) => setFormState({ ...formState, username: e.target.value })}
    />
  );
}
```

```
const Confirmation = () => {
  const formState = useContext(FormStateContext);

  return (
    <div>Your Name: {formState.username}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your components aren't that big, you could do something like this instead of using a different route :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({isConfirmationMode: false});
  const handleChange = e => setState({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});

  const confirm = () => {
    console.log('confirmed');
    // Here send you data or whatever you want
    // then redirect wherever you want, I just display the form again
   setState({...state, isConfirmationMode: false});
  }

  const cancel = () => {
    // juste display the form again
   setState({...state, isConfirmationMode: false});
  }

  const displayForm = () => (
    <div>
      name : <input type="text" name="name" value={state.name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={() => setState({...state, isConfirmationMode: true})}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );

  return state.isConfirmationMode ? 
    <Confirmation name={state.name} confirm={confirm} cancel={cancel} /> : 
    displayForm()
};

// Here I created 'confirm' and 'cancel', but you might only need 'cancel'
const Confirmation = ({name, confirm, cancel}) => {
  return (
    <div> 
      Are you {name} ?<br />
      <button onClick={confirm}>Confirm</button>
      <button onClick={cancel}>Cancel</button>

    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is [the repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-yhthwg). The idea is just to either display the form or a confirmation depending on the state of a simple boolean (I separated the confirmation in another component but here it could be part of the first one).